# Is max. Eigenvalue of k-sparse PCA always $\leq$ max. Eigenvalue of normal PCA on same dataset?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, eigenvalues, sparse, bounds

Is max. Eigenvalue of k-sparse PCA always less than or equal to the max. Eigenvalue of normal PCA on same dataset? K refers to the number of non zero eigenvalues when the dataset is of dimension n < p. I am interested in cases where k is less than p in particular. What about the smallest and second smallest eigenvalues (algebraic connectivity)?

Comment: I do't know how well standardized this is, but looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_PCA#Mathematical_formulation ,it would seem that for the 1st (largest) eigenvalue, both PCA and Sparse PCA are solving the same maximization problem, except for an extra constraint for Sparse PCA, whose solution is the max eigenvalue. Therefore, mac eigenvalue of Sparse PCA $\le$ max eigenvalue of PCA. So other than strict vs. non-strict inequality, you have it backwards, or so it seems to me, having just looked up Sparse PCA for the 1st time.

Comment: What about the smallest and second smallest eigenvalues? The order makes sense otherwise w.r.t largest eigenvalue.

Comment: I addressed the largest eigenvalue. I don't know what can be said about the other eigenvalues - I haven't looked into it.  For the record, my previous comment addressed the original version of your question.